# Is this probability inequality still true if we conditioned the term on a variable?

Tags: inequality, conditional-probability

When I read Part III of this [scientific paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8905131) in telecommunication, I see that the author use the following result from the Jensen Inequality

$E\left[ {\max \left( {X,Y} \right)} \right] \geqslant \max \left[ {E\left( X \right)E\left( Y \right)} \right]$

Where $E\left[ . \right]$ is the expectation operator.

Does the inequality still true if we conditioned on a variable $T$ like this:

${E_{\left\{ T \right\}}}\left[ {\left. {\max \left( {X,Y} \right)} \right|T = t} \right] \geqslant \max \left[ {{E_{\left\{ T \right\}}}\left( {\left. X \right|T = t} \right){E_{\left\{ T \right\}}}\left( {\left. Y \right|T = t} \right)} \right]$

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by $E_{T}$ But normally, you see:
$$ \mathbb{E}_{T}[max(X,Y)| T=t] \ge \mathbb{E}_{T}[X| T=t]$$
and $$ \mathbb{E}_{T}[max(X,Y)| T=t] \ge \mathbb{E}_{T}[Y| T=t]$$
Hence, your conclusion

Comment: ${E_{\left\{ T \right\}}}\left[ . \right]$ mean take the expectation of [] with respect to the random variable $T$. I did not quite catch up with your answer, is this result
${E_{\left\{ T \right\}}}\left[ {\left. {\max \left( {X,Y} \right)} \right|T = t} \right] \geqslant \max \left[ {{E_{\left\{ T \right\}}}\left( {\left. X \right|T = t} \right){E_{\left\{ T \right\}}}\left( {\left. Y \right|T = t} \right)} \right]$ right or wrong ?

Comment: As far as you're concerned, you are safe to say it's right.

Comment: Because of the lack of rigour(which you can ignore) in your statement, I can't say it's true